# In a nutshell explanation of topological defects and charge?

Tags: topological-defects

I read this great answer:

[What is a topological defect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285731/what-is-a-topological-defect)

in which it seems that a topological defect is a region of the domine of a function in which the function is not defined. In fact, [here](https://erozic.github.io/files/Topological_Defects_in_Physics.pdf) it is written that

> Topological defects are parts of the domain where the
> quantity of interest is not necessarily everywhere well
> defined and the configuration is unable to satisfy the
> usual physical criteria

Therefore, my question is: if we have a physical quantity defined by a function $f(R^n)$, so that $\exists x\in R^n/\nexists f(x)$, can we name $x$ as a *topological defect of $f$*? If so, can we say that the topological charge of $f$ is the number of such undefined points of its domine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Defects : topological or not ?**
A topological defect is a region where a physical system has configuration which cannot be continuously deformed into one another (we say that they are *homotopically distinct*).

This happens for fields, which are functions $f:M\to T$ where $T$ is some target space. Broadly speaking, for homotopically distinct configurations to exist, there must be some *holes* in $M$ and $T$. This is the case for example when $f$ is a unit vector field (like a normalized velocity field) (then $T  =\mathbb S^1$). The usual space for $M$ is usually the euclidean plane, which has no holes. If, however, $f$ is not defined at some points $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ in $E_2 = \mathbb R^2$, then we have $M = E_2 \backslash \{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ in which case we say that $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are *topological defect*.

In general, we might call defects physical points which are not in the domain of $f$. Those defects are not necessarily topological though : we also need the condition on the target space $T$. If $f$ is a real scalar field (like temperature), there cannot be topological defects.

**Topological charges**
However, the topological charge is *not* the number of topological defects. At each defect $p_1,\ldots,p_n$, a field configuration $f$ will have some quantity which is invariant when $f$ is continuously  deformed (we say that they are *topologically protected*). Those invariants are called *topological charges*.

In our example ($ M = E_2 \backslash \{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$ and $T = \mathbb S^1$), we can define $n_i$ to be the *winding number* of $f$ around the defect $p_i$. Each $n_i$ can take any integer value.

Comment: Thank you! Great reply!